# JScript - VBScript TypeName function for ActiveXObjects

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Is there a way to determine the `ActiveXObject` type for a variable in JScript?  VBScript has the `TypeName`function but I've not been able to find a suitable counterpart in JScript.  I'm familiar with the `typeof` and `instanceof` operators but neither one return object specific data.

The reason I'm inquiring about this is for a work project.  If possible, I need to avoid using VBScript.  Below are some of the project requirements which I cannot deviate from:

- JScript code will be part of an HTA.
- HTA will be hosted by Internet Explorer 8.
- All computers will be running Windows 7 (32 bit).

The closest I've been able to get with JScript is a true/false value:

```js
var Regex = new ActiveXObject('VBScript.RegExp');
Regex instanceof ActiveXObject; // Returns true
```

With VBScript, however, the `TypeName` function returns the object interface name:

```vb
Dim Regex
Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
TypeName(Regex) ' Returns IRegExp2
```

Here is a complete HTA I made to test the previous results:

### JSTesting.hta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>JScript Testing</TITLE>
<META http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8' />
<SCRIPT language='JScript'>
    new function () {
        var width = 350, height = 120;
        var left = (screen.availWidth - width) / 2;
        var top = (screen.availHeight - height) / 2;
        resizeTo(width, height); moveTo(left, top);
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        var regex = new ActiveXObject('VBScript.RegExp');
        jstest.onclick = vbstest.onclick = function () {
            var id = event.srcElement.id;
            var TypeName = (id === 'jstest') ? JSTypeTest : VBSProc;
            output.innerText = TypeName(regex);
        };
    };
    function JSTypeTest(obj) {
        return (obj instanceof ActiveXObject) ?
        'ActiveXObject' : 'UnknownObject';
    }
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language='VBScript'>
    Dim VBSProc
    Set VBSProc = GetRef("VBSTypeTest")
    Function VBSTypeTest(obj)
        VBSTypeTest = TypeName(obj)
    End Function
</SCRIPT>
<STYLE type='text/css'>
    span {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font: 10pt courier new;
    }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <BUTTON id='jstest'>JScript</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON id='vbstest'>VBScript</BUTTON>
    <HR>
    <SPAN>VBScript.RegExp object = </SPAN>
    <SPAN id='output'></SPAN>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I have no idea what it will give you for ActiveX objects in your target environment, but `Object.prototype.call(theObject)` is well-defined as `"[object TypeName]"` for JavaScript objects. Worth a try. More: [*Say what*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Comment: T.J., I tried your suggestion but it gave me an error 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.  I also tried another version `Object.prototype.toString.call(RegexObj)` which returned `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: @ Chris: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `Object.prototype.toString.call(theObject)` (hopefully the link made that clear). Sounds like it didn't work, though. It was a shot in the dark.

Comment: @ T.J., My apologies for overlooking the link.  At first glance, it seemed to be part of your name.  Epic reading fail on my part :(

Comment: @ Chris: Oh, hey, I see what you mean!